# Verification of proof that for a,b in ring R, assuming ab is a zero divisor at least one of a and b is zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, field-theory

I'm not so sure if this is correct but here's what I have so far:

ab is a zero divisor iff there is a c$\neq$0 s.t. (ab)c=c(ab)=0 given ab$\neq$0 and c$\neq$0.  Then we have (ab)c-c(ab)=0=(ab)c+c-c-c(ab)=0 which breaks down into (ab+1)c-c(1+ab)=0.  We already know c cannot be 0 so for 1+ab=0 ab must equal -1.

Is this what the proof is asking for? If not, how would I correct it?

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not what the proof is asking for. You seem to have the wrong definition of *zero divisor*.

Let's assume that the ring $R$ is commutative for simplicity.

$x\in R$ is a *zero divisor* if there is $y\in R$, $y\ne0$, such that $xy=0$.

Thus, if $ab$ is a zero divisor, then there is $c\in R$, $c\ne0$, such that $(ab)c=0$.

Then, $0=(ab)c=a(bc)$. If $bc=0$, then $b$ is a zero divisor. If $bc\ne0$, then $a$ is a zero divisor.

Comment: But don't you have to incorporate commutativity so that (ab)c=c(ab)=0 here?

Comment: @cambelot, If your ring is not commutative, say it explicitly in the question.

Comment: What I mean is: The definition I have here is that ab in a ring is a zero divisor if ab does not equal to 0 and there is a c not equal to 0 with (ab)c=0 or (ba)c=0.  So shouldn't the last line of your proof be in this format?

Comment: @cambelot, are you sure that's the definition? I mean, what is the definition of "$x$ is zero divisor"? Perhaps you could tell us which book you're using or online notes if any.